# Laravel: A User can have many devices but every device belongs to maximum one user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am a bit stuck.

So I have 2 Models, `User` and `Device`. A User can have X devices but every device can only belong to maximum 1 user.

I've defined the relationships like this:

```
class Device extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User');
    }
}

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function devices()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Device');
    }
}
```

Now, I want an Overview-View for my devices.

```
class DeviceController extends Controller
{
    public function showOverview()
    {
        $devices = Device::all();
        return view('devices.overview')->with('devices', $devices);
    }
}
```

In this View I foreach all my devices.

```
@foreach ($devices as $device)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $device->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $device->serial }}</td>
        <td>{{ $device->state }}</td>
        <td><!-- Get user Name here by $device->user_id Foreign key --></td>
        <td>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-sm">
                <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> Profile
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

There, where the comment is I want go get the user name associated. The foreign key is saved as `$device->user_id` and refers to the id of the users table. How can I get the name of that user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should eager load related user for all devices to avoid additional database query for every time you access related **User** model.

Replace

```
$devices = Device::all();
```

with

```
$devices = Device::with('user')->get();
```

Secondly, in order to access related **User** object in your template just do the following:

```
<td>{{ $device->user->name }}</td>
```

Comment: Thank you. But when accessing my Route I get this error: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::all()` after replacing it like you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

```
$device->user->name // or other properties of user
```

In `Device` Model

```
return $this->belongsTo("App\User");
```

`hasOne` should be used when the foreign key isn't in the referencing table. In your case, the foreign key `user_id` is in the referencing table `devices`, hence this is a`belongsTo` relationship

Answer (score 0):

You have the correct relation setup on your User model, however the inverse of that relationship on your Device model should be using the `belongsTo()` method, instead of the `hasOne()` method.

```
class Device extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(App\User::class);
    }
}
```

You should then be able to fetch the user's name for a given device using the following in your blade template.

```
{{ $device->user->name }}
```

As you're also accessing the user relationship for each model as you're looping over the device results, you may wish to eager load the user relationship to minimise the amount of queries to your database

```
$devices = Device::with('user')->get();
```

You can also query devices just for the given user

```
$user->devices
```